# to show a special polynomial is not a square of another polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

The following is a problem which looks likes elementary but I can not solve it. But I am very interesting know the answer to it. I also think it deserves a decent solution personally, so that I can not stopping thinking over it.

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $Q$ be a power of $p$. Denote by $\mathbb{F}_Q$ the finite field with $Q$ elements and denote by $k$ the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_Q$. Suppose $n>1$ is a positive integer and $A\in \mathbb{F}_Q$ with $A\notin \{0,+1,-1\}$. Consider the polynomial $f(x):=(x^{2n}-A)^2(x-1)^2+(1-A^2)(x^{4n}-1)(x-1)\in \mathbb{F}_Q[x]$. I hope to show that $f(x)$ is not a square of another polynomial in $k[x]$. In the context I got this question, $Q=q^2$, $a\in \mathbb{F}_{q^2}^*$ with $a^{q+1}\neq 1$ and $A=a^{(q+1)/2}$. You may assume these if you like.

In the special case that the characteristic $p$ divides $n$, it is true since each root $\alpha\neq 1$ of $f(x)$ in the field $k$ is simple. Surely it needs to check such a root indeed exists. In fact, my original question can be solved by solving this special case. But I am very curious about what will happen in the case $p$ does not divide $n$. I have tested for some small values of $n$ and wrote out the square roots of $f(x)$ in the ring $k[[x]]$ of formal power series. The square roots are never polynomials of degree $2n+1$ in all examples I tried. Note here $n>1$, since $f(x)$ could be a square if $n=1$. Furthermore, I guess any root $\alpha\neq 1$ of $f(x)$ is simple in the general case. So I tried to calculate the discriminant of the polynomial $f(x)/(x-1)^2$. But again I failed to show the discriminant is nonzero.

I am wondering what is the point I missed to notice? I will appreciate all kinds of solutions and suggestions about this particular question, or about the general and practical way to detrermine if a given polynomial over is a square of another polynomial.

Comment: Are you familiar with computing the GCD of $f (x) $ and its derivative to identify repeated factors?

Comment: @hardmath I think I am familiar with that. But I can not compute the gcd in this example. Surely you can solve the problem if you can show the degree of gcd is less than the half of the degree of $f(x)$. Thank You!

Comment: Related: [How do we check if a polynomial is a perfect square?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919195/how-do-we-check-if-a-polynomial-is-a-perfect-square) and [your similar Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871125/when-is-a-given-polynomial-a-square-of-another-polynomial) from about three months ago.

Comment: Unless $(1 + 4 n + A (-1 + 4 n))=0$ we have that $x=-1$ is a zero of multiplicity exactly two, and [my answer to your earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1871345/11619) works verbatim. So if $A$ is not in the prime field, the case is settled. This polynomial is palindromic as well :-)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thanks for your comments here and your former answer. But I think here in this case $x=-1$ is not a root of $f(x)$. Isn't it?

Comment: You are right, sorry. I meant $x=1$. That is clearly a double root, and the question is whether it might have a higher multiplicity. The condition I stated comes from the third derivative $f'''(1)=0$.

Comment: I took $g(x) = f(x)/(x-1)^2$ and got the same condition for $g(1)$ to be zero, i.e. it requires $(1+4n + A(-1+4n))=0$.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen and hardmath: Yes, $x=1$ is a root of multiplicity two if $(1+4n+A(-1+4n))\neq 0$, so in this case the degree of $f(x)$ should be congruent to $2$ modulo $4$. Indeed this degree is $4n+2$.

Comment: Ahh. Good point! I forgot about that. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahttonen: Thanks a lot for your interest. Actually, I tried to use your method but I failed to get more information this time. As I mentioned above, in case the characteristic divides $n$, then all the other roots are simple. Thus in this special case we are done. In the general case, I also tried to get some information on the multiplicity of roots other than $1$. But I can not succeed in this direction.